# Poor contrast on "custom flag too long" message in dark mode

Tags: bug, feature-request, design, error-message

*This also happens in SOfT, but that isn't considered on-topic here.*.

When flagging a comment (or post) in dark mode on Stack Overflow, and the message is too long, the warning/error is somewhat difficult to read.

Here's how it currently looks.

[image]

May I suggest `--red-900` instead? While somewhat more pink-ish, I find that shade to be much more readable. I think it also has a change in contrast ratio from 1.9 to 6.4, although I'm not sure exactly what that measures.

[image]

Comment: As seen in previous meta posts, we are working on updating all of our colors and I am fairly confident that this will be fixed with that change. We are roughly a month out from launching those changes, so please hold tight :)

Comment: What is SOfT?..

Comment: @PetəíŕdTheLinuxWizard the "Teams" product

Comment: @PetəíŕdTheLinuxWizard It's short for Stack Overflow for Teams. See [this](https://stackoverflow.co/teams/our-solution/) for a page about it